# Decoupling on Power-on-reset-IC

Tags: microcontroller, digital-logic, decoupling-capacitor, reset, decoupling

Is it a good idea to place the usual 100nF decoupling capacitor on a power-on-reset chip? Mightn't that influence its behavior on brown-out or power dips?

What is the best approach here?

The power-on-reset IC is a [Micrel MIC803](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/268/mic803-778690.pdf). I could not find any info on this on SE or in the datasheet. The reference circuit does not show a decoupling capacitor, but many reference circuits don't even if it is advisable to put one in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The datasheet link does say that additional glitch immunity can be achieved with a 100nF bypass cap.

So basically it does not need it in general and case by case it can be determined if it is necessary. If PCB area is not an issue, draw a place for the cap but decide later to mount it.

Comment: It does, perhaps I have somehow overlooked it. Thanks for pointing it out!